# can't show dialog in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, progressdialog, android-fragmentactivity

I wanna show a progress dialog in fragment but it throws an exception stating that the requestFeature() must be called before setting the content. here's my code:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    private Dialog _pDialog;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getActivity());
        _pDialog.setContentView(R.layout.myprogressdialog);
        _pDialog.show();
    }
}
```

it throws the exception at `.show()`. any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I feel so stupid for the mistake I've made, _pDialog was declared as Dialog and then initialized as PogressDialog, that was causing the exception to be thrown, I've changed it to this:

```
_pDialog = new Dialog(this.getActivity());
```

and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Do that in `OncreateView` or `Onactivitycreated`..

you can just use

```
_pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

to create custom Dialog use this

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
// Get the layout inflater
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

// Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
// Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.customdialogui, null))
// Add action buttons
       .setPositiveButton(R.string.signin, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // do something..
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
           }
       });      
return builder.create();
```

check this link for more information about dialogs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html